# Thymeleaf resource routes behind proxy

Tags: spring, proxy, thymeleaf

I've got a spring application with thymeleaf templates deployed in a local tomcat7, and served to the outside world via an apache proxy. The base urls are:

- Tomcat: http://some.ip.address:8080/my-application
- Apache proxy: http://www.appdomain.com

The problem i've got is that if i link a css file in a template like:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="../../../resources/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"
    th:href="@{/resources/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css}"
    rel="stylesheet" />
```

The generated code looks like:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="/my-application/resources/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

So it works when accessed via localhost:8080 (tomcat), but not via proxy because of the generated '/my-application' part.

Does anybody know how to fix this and make the application work ok in both environments?

Comment: Can you post an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

On your Thymeleaf layout/template, I have the path like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css" h:href="@{/static/css/bootstrap.css}" />
```

Have your static folder in the root of your classpath and add resource mapping if you are using java config (which I prefer over xml)

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
}
```

or in XML

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
```